# Laravel 4 - Render recursive @include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

I'd like to get the rendered string of a template with recursive @include tags. Unfortunately it seems that the `render()` method doesn't support recursivity:

```
return View::make('bind', $data)->render();
```

This is my view:

```
{{$namespace}}\Decorators\{{$decorators[$i++]}}
<?php $tab = str_repeat("\t", $i) ?>

{{$tab}}(
    {{$tab}}new @if(count($decorators) < $i)@include('bind')@endif

{{$tab}})
```

---

This is what I should get:

```
Workflows\Decorators\Foo
(
    new Workflows\Decorators\Bar
    (
        new 
    )
)
```

This is what I get:

```
Workflows\Decorators\Foo
(
    new @include('bind')
)
```

Nevertheless if I display the view instead of rendering it, I can see the correct source code.

Is there a way to render views recursively?

Comment: Put the @ directives on different lines?  I believe there is a limitation that stipulates one @ thing per line.

Comment: @bishop can't believe it was that simple, thanks! Please add your answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: There you go!  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel requires that `@` directives appear on separate lines.  Said another way, only one at sign per line.  In some cases, Laravel gives you a compile error: in others, you just get mysterious results (as was your case).

So, rewrite your code as below and it should work:

```
@if (count($decorators) < $i)
    @include('bind')
@endif
```